# Cut string of text after a character from a column each line of a csv, keeping the other columns, and printing to a new file

Tags: bash, sed, cut

I have a CSV file with a first column that reads:

/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/BER5_OSSD_F008071.csv.0.01.out.csv

Followed by additional columns listing counts pulled from other CSV files.

What I want is to remove "/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/" from each line without affecting any other part of the file.

I've tried using sed, grep, and cut, but that only seems to print the output in the terminal or a new file only containing that part of the line, and not the rest of the columns. Can I remove the "/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/" and keep everything else the same?

Comment: `awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' file.csv` ?

Comment: `sed 's|^.*OSSD_Output/||' <<< '/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/BER5_OSSD_F008071.csv.0.01.out.csv'`

Comment: `sed 's|^.*OSSD_Output/||' file.csv`

Comment: cut -d/ -f7- file.csv ?

Comment: An example of the data you're working with and an example of how you want it to look after will help people answer the question for you.

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry I went straight into the lab after posting the question. I've tried the first three comments and they are not what I'm after. The first @User123 printed them in the terminal, but did not alter the csv, which is what I'm after. The next two by Jetchisel didn't alter it either and printed the file name in the terminal.

Comment: @Altaf The second one worked and made the new file! Much appreciated, and thank you very much! I would give you an upvote, but I don't have enough karma (or what they use on here).

Comment: @Shem: To alter the csv files in-place, you can try: `echo "$(awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' file.csv)" > file.csv` or by using `sed` as mentioned by @Jetchisel, use `-i` to edit the file in-place: `sed -i 's|^.*OSSD_Output/||' file.csv` .

Comment: @mattb I'm really not sure how to do this. What is the best way? A screen shot? or some other way? I've asked a few questions before and I always try to do it right, but I keep messing it up. Hopefully I'll get better at is as I keep learning!

Comment: @Shem, no worries - if you put a backtick ` character around a word it will highlight it as code, or if you select a few lines of your answer and press `ctrl + k` it will indent it and make it like code style. Those are the two main things I use. See here for more formatting options: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk to get this job done.
Please see below code which will replace the contents`/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/` with `""` empty and will update the operation in the same file with the option `inplace`
`yourfile.csv` is the input file.

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/\/Users\/swilki\/Desktop\/Africa_OSSD\/OSSD_Output\//,"")}1' yourfile.csv
```

The above will remove the "/Users/swilki/Desktop/Africa_OSSD/OSSD_Output/" and keep everything else same.
**Output of yourfile.csv**: 
BER5_OSSD_F008071.csv.0.01.out.csv

**Option 2, If you want to print in a new file**:
Below code will be give the replaced contents in the new file `your_newfile.csv`

```
awk '{sub(/\/Users\/swilki\/Desktop\/Africa_OSSD\/OSSD_Output\//,"")}1' yourfile.csv >your_newfile.csv
```